# How to enable syntax prompts and highlighting in the Scapy interpreter without using sudo privileges during startup?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, sudo, scapy

I'm looking for a solution to enable syntax prompts and highlighting in the scapy shell without use sudo privileges.

Scapy runed with sudo:
[image: Scapy runed with sudo]

Scapy runed without sudo:
[image: Scapy runed without sudo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have different python setup for `sudo` and non sudo.

A good option would be to use

```
sudo python -m pip install ipython
```

So that you are sure the sudo setup installs it